# Make a checkbox readonly in visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, community

I want a `Checkbox` which is set by default(check). I do not want users to `check` OR `uncheck` it. In other words we can say it, I want to make it read only.

How do I do this in `visualforce` page ? Please help me out here. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can just disable it

```
<apex:inputCheckbox disabled="true" />
or
<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" id="ckcBox"/>
```

Le

Answer (score 1):

```
<apex:inputCheckbox value="{!field__c}" id="checkbox"/>
```

you could use Jquery functions to check and disable.